# Connection error on config server from mongos router in mongodb sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-shell

So, I am performing mongodb sharding with 1 router(mongos), 1 config server and 2 shards. I've configured the servers and when I try to run

`mongos --configdb config/<ip-of-config>:27017`

I get this error:

`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-28T07:26:25.557+00:00"},"s":"I", "c":"-", "id":4333222, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM received error response","attr":{"host":"127.0.0.1:27017","error":"HostUnreachable: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused","replicaSet":"config","response":{}}}
```

this is my config file for config db

mongod.conf

```
# for documentation of all options, see:

# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.

storage:

dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb

# engine:

# wiredTiger:



# where to write logging data.

systemLog:

destination: file

logAppend: true

path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log



# network interfaces

net:

port: 27017

bindIp: 0.0.0.0



# how the process runs

processManagement:

timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo



replication:

replSetName: "config"



sharding:

clusterRole: configsvr
```

Can anyone help me????

I tried changing localhost IP to 0.0.0.0 but id di nothing. I don't know what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you start the config server? Did you initiate the replica set on config server?

Comment: yes I did. By runnin rs.initiate() and checked it by running rs.status()

Comment: Default port for `mongos` is 27017, but you use this port already on config server. Do you run them on the same machine? If not, did you check the firewall settings?

Comment: Already disabled firewall and yes they are on different machines

Comment: According to your config file you did not setup [Internal/Membership Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/). I don't know if you can run a sharded cluster without Membership Authentication (parameter `security.clusterAuthMode` defaults to `keyFile`), the documentation is not 100% clear in that point. But for sure, it would be a "no-go" anyway.